# Where are replays saved for Rocket League on PC

Tags: rocket-league

Where are replays saved for Rocket League on PC?

Can you please provide the location?

And is it possible to play these videos with a media player of some kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://steamcommunity.com/app/252950/discussions/0/537402115080081075/), they should be saved here

> `<My Documents>/My Games/Rocket League/TAGame/Demos`